# Modify the dates inside the ResultTable to local time from utc

Tags: c#, datetime, gridview

I have a small issue, basically, I get some values from a particular source, where everything is saved in UTC date time format, but i would like to display it in normal our local date time.

So I have a 
ResultTable resultsTable = ... values

And this table i bind to a  GridView.

So where or how can i modify the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try the above. Type the format you want and culture you want

```
string x = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or
    string x = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: yeah but when? how on itembound or...?

Comment: Before bound datatable with gridview do a loop and change values.

Comment: oh extra loop, isnt very good :( any other way around, more effecient?

Comment: when retrieving data from database(on select statement) use for example CONVERT(nvarchar(10), youdatefield, 103).